# Apache Tomcat 6.0 IIS 5.1 isapi redirector error "The request is not supported."

Tags: tomcat6, iis-5, isapi-redirect

I am facing this problem since many days, scratched each n every piece of code again n again, but couldn't rectify it...

I ve installed Apache Tomcat 6.0 on windows XP- service pack 3 & Enabled IIS 5.1.

Tomcat is running on port 8080 and iis is running on port 80.

I ve struts application which uses SMTP service of IIS...

**WORKER.PROPERTIES which i've kept in [TOMCAT]/conf/ is as follows**

```
worker.list=wlb,jkstatus,wlb1

worker.ajp13w.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13w.host=localhost
worker.ajp13w.port=8009

worker.ajp13w1.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13w1.host=192.168.1.87
worker.ajp13w1.port=8009

worker.wlb.type=lb
worker.wlb.balance_workers=ajp13w
worker.wlb1.balance_workers=ajp13w1

worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

**URIWORKERMAP.PROPERTIES is as follows**

```
/admin/*=wlb
/manager/*=wlb
/examples/*=wlb
/jkmanager=jkstatus
```

I've done changes in regedit. Screen shot of REGISTRY EDITORS is as follows.

[image]
I've placed isapi_redirector in /bin directory.

Added a virtual directory pointing to /bin and named as jakarta.

Added isapi filter and it is showing as per the below attachment...[image: ISAPI FILTER Snapshot]

When I enter `http://localhost:8080/examples/` in my browser I will get the result.

But when I enter `http://localhost/examples/` I am getting an error **"The request is not supported."**

I am not getting how to trace.